# ¿Como leer datos de tipo caracter dentro de una condicional if?

Tags: c, if

Mi problema radica en que de acuerdo a un numero entero, por ejemplo 1, la condicional se cumpliría y por lo tanto, tendría que leer el dato que estoy solicitando, de tipo carácter. Al realizar esta acción, al momento de introducir el numero 1 me finaliza el programa sin leer mi dato de tipo carácter.
Este es un ejemplo, solo es de prueba y es corto, agradecería que me ayudaran con esta duda, gracias:
Las variables declaradas son palabras al azar, lo importante es el código.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int torta;
    char dia;

    scanf("%d",&torta);

        if(torta == 1){
            printf("Ingresa una letra");
            scanf("%c",&dia);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en el buffer de entrada que queda en el teclado. Cuando haces `scanf("%d",&torta);` guardas un numero entero en la variable torta. Si pones un 1 entra en la condición. En ella, pides recoger un carácter `scanf("%c",&dia);` pero se lo "salta" por que en ella se guarda el "enter" del `scanf("%d",&torta);`

Para solucionar de manera sencilla, tan solo has de poner un espacio en blanco delante del `" %c"`.

Quedaría así:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int torta;
    char dia;

    scanf("%d",&torta);

        if(torta == 1){
            printf("Ingresa una letra");
            scanf(" %c",&dia); //<-- Insertar espacio en blanco
        }
    return 0;
}
```